# How to recreate a wave that moves like in Interstellar?

Tags: modeling

I would like to know how to recreate a moving background wave. Which would be as tall in height as that of interstellar.

[image]

Comment: That was very little detail. Looked up the scene in question. Do you need the wave to move three dimensionally? If it’s just a background, this is very easy with shader nodes. If it has to move three dimensionally, that’s a bit trickier. I’m guessing the movie creators switched between possibly still imagery of a wave distant, and 3D models up close.

Comment: it's gonna be like a plan of the horizon and at the back we saw a huge wave moving towards us.

Comment: How can i do it with just some nodes ? how to give the impression that its moving ?

Comment: As I mentioned, it’s only really possible as a node based world background if you don’t need it to move three dimensionally like it does in the film. I suspect the one in the film is actually two things: at first, it’s a distant background image that might even be node based. At second, it’s 3D modeling up close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another picture from the film:

[image]

You could use the *Ocean* modifier on a flat plane, give it foam, put a camera 180° over it and render a sequence, then project the rendered movie on a subdivided plane that you deform with a curve or with a *Lattice*. Also deform its surface a bit with a *Displace* modifier. Put a bit of additional effect on the top (particles, even a plane that is half opaque with a *Noise* as factor to create rain)